# [RootModel setAppLevel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class called RootModel.  In RootModel.h I have:

```
@interface RootModel : NSObject {
    NSString *appLevel;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *appLevel;

In RootModel.m I have the following:

#import "RootModel.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
@implementation RootModel
@synthesize   appLevel;
#pragma mark Singleton Methods

static RootModel *sharedObject = nil;

+(id)sharedModel {
    @synchronized(self){
        if(sharedObject == nil)
            sharedObject = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];

    }
    return sharedObject;
}

in MainViewController.m I have:
RootModel *rm = [RootModel sharedModel];
rm.appLevel = @"0";
```

The last statement give me [RootModel setAppLevel:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
It should be noted that everything was working fine with the above code.  My project somehow got corrupted and I built a new project using the files and now I get this error.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

in RootModel.h

```
@class MainViewController;//note Here

@interface RootModel : NSObject {

           NSString *appLevel;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *appLevel;

+(id)sharedModel;//Note Here

@end
```

You may have forgotten this method

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

    return [[self sharedManager] retain];

}
```

Take a look at [this](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/).

Comment: I have that already.  This code was working before and started to give me this error after I copied file to a new project.